# Problems with Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm using a javascript library (jquery.dataTables.1.js) and am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fnSetData' of undefined jquery.dataTables.1.js?body=1:785
_fnSetCellData jquery.dataTables.1.js?body=1:785
_fnGatherData jquery.dataTables.1.js?body=1:542
(anonymous function) jquery.dataTables.1.js?body=1:6593
jQuery.extend.each jquery.js?body=1:612
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery.js?body=1:242
DataTable jquery.dataTables.1.js?body=1:6169
(anonymous function) segment_dashboard.js?body=1:51
fire jquery.js?body=1:975
self.fireWith jquery.js?body=1:1085
jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js?body=1:407
DOMContentLoaded
```

Any thoughts on what this could be?

Comment: Either the library is broken, or you're using it wrong. Without seeing a minimal code sample that exhibits this behaviour, it would be very hard to help you.

Comment: It was actually working perfectly fine, then I added a header col and inserted this into the table `<td class="ra"><%= rounded_number_to_currency(10.00)%></td>` and it's throwing the error now.